# How to get server (VPS) memory usage history?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vps, memory-usage

I am using a 512MB Ubuntu 12 VPS. I'd like to get a daily (maximum) memory consumption log, as a reference to add more memory or not.

Is there a tool for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) for trending your system statistics.

```
$ sudo apt-get install munin munin-node
```

This will install two packages, `munin` for aggregating data and `munin-node` for collection of data from your system. When munin has been running for a while, you can take a look at the visualized data from it and consider if you need more memory or not.

By default, munin will create HTML-files in the directory `/var/cache/munin/www`. Serve these files by a web server and start watching your system trends.

It is also a great tool for trending other statistics.

Answer (score 0):

For detailed statistics, install sysstat and learn how to use sar(1). You know you need more memory when the paging traffic goes high.